# Event listener seems so disappear once I use the same code to add the listener to another element

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

So, this has been bugging me for quite a while.

I have a javascript constructor that goes smth like this:

```
function TimeBlock(c, local_count){
    /* creates a timeblock */
    .
    .
    .
    _getel(this.id).addEventListener('mouseover', this.displayPopup)
    _getel(this.id).addEventListener('mouseout', this.killPopup)
}
```

and basically it creates a TimeBlock object and assigns to it those two event handlers, which are defined in TimeBlock.prototype like so:

```
TimeBlock.prototype = {
    .
    .
    .
    block = getTimeBlock(e.target.id)
    //do something
    },

    killPopup: function(e){
    // //do something else
    }
}
```

And it works. I call `new Timeblock (some_parameters)` and i get my timeblock, it creates the element into the html (it's a div) and assigns the listener to it. I test it and it works fine. But as soon as I call it again, I get a new TimeBlock element created, with working listeners, but the previous one stops working. It's like assigning those listeners onto the new element cancels out the listeners that should be on the previous element.

What is even weirder is that I've assigned those listeners manually through a javascript console and it worked fine there. I'm using Firefox 7.0.1 and Firebug for those tests.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Side note: `addEventListener` isn't supported in IE until IE9, so unless you can ignore IE6, IE7, and IE8 users, you'll need to use `addEventListener` if it's there, or `attachEvent` (Microsoft's original version) if it isn't. This isn't the problem you're having (it's the *next* problem you'll have ;-) ). Or, of course, use any good JavaScript library [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) like to smooth over these diffs for you.

Comment: I don't think the 'this' is the problem here. I've tried setting those functions as global functions achieving the same (flawed) results.

Comment: `@user`: Don't know what else to tell you, fundamentally hooking things up properly doesn't result in the behavior you describe. I've updated my answer with another thought, and with a working example demonstrating the technique I described.

Answer (score 0):

This code is suspicious:

```
_getel(this.id).addEventListener('mouseover', this.displayPopup)
```

...because although you're hooking up the function as an event handler, you're not doing anything to preserve what `this` means inside the handler. So when the handler is called, `this` will *not* be the same as it was in the code above. I suspect this loss of what `this` means is what's causing the effect you're seeing when you try to do this with more than one `TimeBlock` instance.

There are various ways to ensure that your functions are called with the correct `this` value, one of which looks like this:

```
function TimeBlock(c, local_count){
    /* creates a timeblock */
    .
    .
    .
    var self = this;
    _getel(this.id).addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
        self.displayPopup(event);
    });
    _getel(this.id).addEventListener('mouseout', function(event) {
        self.killPopup(event);
    });
}
```

More reading:

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

The only other thing that comes to mind is that `mouseover` and `mouseout` **bubble** to parent elements, which can be confusing if you're not careful. So for instance, if you have:

```
<div>Foo <span>bar</span></div>
```

...and you watch for `mouseover` and `mouseout` on the `div`, you'll see `mouseout` when the mouse moves from the `span` ("bar") into the `div` ("foo"), which can be surprising if you're not expecting it.

---

Here's an example demonstrating two, independent instances hooked to independent elements as per the above ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/ilawup)):

```
window.onload = function() {

    new TimeBlock("firstElement");
    new TimeBlock("secondElement");

    function _getel(id) {
      return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    function TimeBlock(id){
        var self = this;
        this.id = id;
        this.counter = 0;
        _getel(this.id).addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
            self.displayPopup(event, this);
        });
        _getel(this.id).addEventListener('mouseout', function(event) {
            self.killPopup(event, this);
        });
    }

    TimeBlock.prototype.displayPopup = function(event, element) {
        ++this.counter;
        element.innerHTML = "Display, counter = " + this.counter;
    };

    TimeBlock.prototype.killPopup = function(event, element) {
        element.innerHTML = "Remove, counter = " + this.counter;
    };

};
```

Comment: smth still isn't right. Since adding listeners from the console worked fine, i tried replicating exactly what i was typing in the console. I created a string like so:
's="_getel(\"" + this.id + "\").addEventListener("mouseover", my_handler)"'

then i displayed the string through using 'alert()' to be sure it's correct , and then ran it with 'eval()'. Same behavior: create first object with working listeners, listeners disappear as i create the 2nd object. Listeners work on the last created object.

Comment: @user986730: **Show your non-working code** and we'll point out for you why it isn't working. The code you've shown is largely fine (you have `=` where you should have `:` in one place) other than the issue listed above.